# Generating Polymer documentation

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, documentation, polymer-cli

I am trying to create a Polymer element repository, where all of the elements will have proper documentation and demo pages.

My main source of knowledge is the official [Document your elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/documentation) page.

It covers all regarding writing the docs and how to view them locally as you write them using the `polymer serve` command

However, it does *not* cover how to compile the documentation for publishing on a production server.

**My question is simple**: how can one compile the element documentation so that is can be published on a (static?) HTTP server, where the use of `polymer serve` is *not* desired.

Comment: On your server you can create a page that leaves links for each of the index.html

Comment: I have found out in the meantime that the documentation does not need any compiling and that all of the comment parsing is done inside the `iron-component-page` element. However, I have issues setting everything up - mostly with resolving the path to the `bower_components` folder. Will update my question when I get to it.

Comment: I think you should close this question by answering it yourself and ask a new one when needed